# X forwarding over SSH not working from remote hosts in Ubuntu guest session

Tags: ssh, xorg, guest-session

I'm currently visiting a research institute and logging into a computer using the guest session option (that saves no data) in Ubuntu 16.04.3.  I'm trying to SSH into the machines I usually work from with X forwarding but getting error messages that don't seem to be related to the `DISPLAY` variable.

Here's an example, with the identifying data scrubbed:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0

$ ssh -X <username@remotehost.com>
Password:
Last login: Wed Oct 25 09:34:04 2017 from <IP address>
$ xlogo
connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: Permission denied
Error: Can't open display: localhost:32.0
$ exit
```

On another server, I get the same error but with `localhost:12.0` rather than `localhost:32.0`.  I'm sure the servers are working/correctly configured because X forwarding works fine on my laptop (running Fedora 26 and where I'm logged in as a normal user).

I've tried various permutations of changing `$DISPLAY` to other values (`:0.0` and `localhost:0.0` among them) but to no avail.  The object `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` exists on the local machine:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
srwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 24 17:15 /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

On one of the remote machines, there are files/objects `X2`, `X26` and `X3` instead of `X0` with different ownerships.  On the other server, the file exists but has permissions `-rw-r--r--`.  But I don't think any of that's relevant because I can forward to my laptop.  There, `X0` exists with permissions `srwxrwxr-x.`.

My suspicion is that this might be a permission issue, either because of the centrally-administrated firewall on this machine or because of something about the guest session.  But Googling the error messages has only led to a lot of ~5 year old posts about setting up Windows machines.

I can provide any other information that's helpful, I'm just not sure what that might be!

Comment: The guest session permissions are restricted using AppArmor. You may want to study and possibly edit the `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm` file.

Comment: That's a great start, @GunnarHjalmarsson! I don't understand AppArmor syntax but I'm guessing the file basically lists things the user can see/run. Possibly relevant here is the line `unix (connect, receive, send) type=stream peer=(addr="@/tmp/.X11-unix/X[0-9]*"),` But that sounds like it's granting access to the object in my error message, rather than denying it...

Comment: I can't help with the details, unfortunately. There is [this documentation](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/Documentation).